Proper escape sequence for this Git command to execute in Groovy?
I want to list all Git tags on my repo, so I do this
$ git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname:short) %(creatordate:short)' refs/tags | grep -E '^sb|^st|^pr'

which prints all the tags that start with sb|st|pr, with the output that looks like this
pr-2024-10-03-1 2024-10-03
sb-2024-10-03-13-14.50.34 2024-10-03
st-2024-10-03-3-15.10.27 2024-10-03
st-2024-10-03-4-22.11.39 2024-10-03
sb-2024-10-03-14-15.50.35 2024-10-03
sb-2024-10-03-15-16.50.42 2024-10-03

I want to process this output, so I attempted this Groovy script
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

String cmd = "git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname:short) %(creatordate:short)' refs/tags | grep -E '^sb|^st|^pr'"
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println proc.text

But I get no output. If I change the command to just do ls -al for example, I do get an output. I'm deducing that I don't have the proper escape sequences for the "'" and "%" in the command? So what's the proper escape sequence? Thanks.

Never-ever use String.execute - always go with List.execute
